# Почему не срабатывает анимация?

Tags: html, css, css-animation, keyframes

Всем привет. На айфонах при обновлении страницы с очисткой кэша не работает анимация. На других устройствах все работает правильно. В devtools также работает правильно, а вот на айфонах нет. После повторного обновления страницы все также работает правильно, только при обновлении с очисткой кэша анимация не работает. Если кто-то знает в чем может быть такая проблема, расскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.
[Ссылка](http://webdevep.takercorporation.com) на сайт. Портфолио - блок с ноутбуком (там и происходит анимация). Увидеть баг можно на айфоне.

```
.portfolio__slider_site_example {
    transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
    width: 216px;
    animation: 80s infinite linear portfolio;
    -webkit-animation: 80s infinite linear portfolio;
  }
  @keyframes portfolio {
    from {
      transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
    }
    to {
      transform: translate(-50%, -88%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -88%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes portfolio {
    from {
      transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
    }
    to {
      transform: translate(-50%, -88%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -88%);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Меняй местами префикстную и нормальную версию везде и проверяй ещё раз.

Comment: @Qwertiy не помогло((

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить префикс -icab (альтернативный браузер Apple)

Например: -icab-transform:;

Comment: Эм.. А можно ссылку на какой-нибудь достоверный источник?

Comment: Не помогло. Но спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy http://yapro.ru/web-master/css/vendornie-prefiksi.html